# Calculate Duration in python list

Tags: duration, calc

Pl suggest a simple logic to sum the duration

Input: ['2 years 4 months', '1 year 9 months', '5 months', '2 months', '2 months', 1 month]

Expected: [4 years 11 months]

Answer (score 0):

It's not an optimized solution, but its simple and working.

```
duration = ['2 years 4 months', '1 year 9 months', '5 months', '2 months', '2 months', 
'1 month']


years = 0
months  = 0

# splitting each value by space

for item in duration:
    # data will a hold a list of all the years and months with the string 'year' and 'month'
    # example  - ['2','years','4','months']
    data = item.split(' ')
    
    # if years mentioned in data that means there is a year to add in the sum 
    if 'year' in data or 'years' in data:
        # the first value of the data list is a year
        # adding year to the sum of years
        years+=int(data[0])

    # if months mentioned in data that means there is a month value to add in the months
    if 'month' in data or 'months' in data:
        # unlike years month can be on 0th index or 2th index
        # so the value of month can be (index of 'months' or 'month') - 1  
        index = data.index('month') if 'month' in data else data.index('months')
        months+=int(data[index-1])


# If months are more than 12 we need to increase a year accordingly
# so we can just devide the months by 12 the result will be years to add remainder will be months 

if months >= 12:
    #doing integer devision so we don't get the value in decimal
    years += months // 12
    months = months % 12

print(years,"years", months, "months")
```

**Output**
4 years 11 months